# Is is possible to query django ORM by last updated object?

Tags: django

I know I can easily grab the latest entered object, but assuming an update is made to an object in the middle of the pack lets say object 50 of 100, is there a way to query the database to grab that latest update? I.e.  number 50, since it was the latest to be updated as opposed to entered into the db?

I searched online and couldn't find anybody trying to accomplish this.

Thanks,

Comment: Is there any field like `mtime` or `updated_at` ?

Comment: that's a good question, I do have a datetime on the object in question, but I'll have to check my models to see if that is set to automatically prefill with the update time, if not I'm sure Django south could help me there.  I suppose this was a dumb question, the real solution is to add that updated_at field when you plan out your models :)

Comment: If you have `updated_at` field, you can use `Model.objects.latest('update_at')` to get the last updated object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your model have a [`DateTimeField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField) with [`auto_now=True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now), you can use [`QuerySet.latest`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.latest) method with that field name specified.

For example, assuming that `Model` has a field DateTimeField `updated_at` with `auto_now` set:

```
last = Model.objects.lastest('updated_at')
```